# How do I make Cesium points rotate with the map?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cesiumjs

I'm building a cesium app and I need my points to indicate a rotational heading. I'm using billboards to display an image I created to show this heading; however, when I rotate the globe, the points don't rotate with it, making the heading indicators incorrect.

In other words, the rotation of my billboards stay constant with the screen space, but not with the globe.

Here's an aerial view of New York. The points in question are in the lower left corner of the image. Note that the heading indicators are pointing northeast.

[image: NYC]

Here's the same view, but rotated 180° so that up is South. Now, the heading indicators are still pointing to the northwest of the *screen*, but I need it to be pointing to the *globe's* northeast, i.e. towards Manhattan.

[image: NYC flipped]

Here's the code that displays a point:

```
var entity = {
    id: data.cluster_number + '_' + point.id,
    name: point.id,
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(point.lon, point.lat),
    billboard: {
        image: 'assets/img/point.png',
        color: color,
        rotation: -1 * toRadians(point.heading),
        scale: point.size * 0.07
    }
};

if (!angular.isDefined(viewer.entities.getById(entity.id))) {
    viewer.entities.add(entity);
}
```

What's the easiest/most effective way to get the points to rotate with the globe/map?

Comment: I know nothing about Cesium, but looking at the maths there, `-1 * angle` is not the same as rotating by a half circle. It's a reflected angle, so 1 degree becomes -1, 45 degrees becomes -45, etc. You probably want `rotation: Cesium.Math.PI + toRadians(point.heading)` instead (as 2π is a full rotation, so adding π adds a half-rotation)

Comment: The rotation property for a billboard in cesium works by starting at north and going counter-clockwise. The angle I have indicates an angle starting from north and going clockwise. The -1 is used to account for that reversal. The angle is correct, I just have this rotation issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a few things.

1 - Update the rotation property of the billboard to be a [CesiumCallbackProperty](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/CallbackProperty.html).

```
rotation: new Cesium.CallbackProperty(
  function () {
    return -1 * toRadians(point.heading);
  }, false);
```

2 - You'll need to update the heading property of the point based on the [camera's heading](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html?classFilter=camera#heading).

```
point.heading = viewer.camera.heading;
```

3 - You'll want to update that point on an interval, either using the cesium clock:

```
mapContext.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function() {...});
```

or using JavaScripts `setInterval`

Once all that is set up here is how it works.
The billboard on the map continuosly pulls the rotation from the point, and if it changes, it will update the billboard on the map. Each time the interval or clock ticks, the value being used changes, based on the heading of the camera.

NOTE: The heading property on the camera is in radians.

Comment: Does this really solve the problem in the best way? Forcing a redraw every time may work well for a few points, but if you have a hundred you risk slowing down the application.

Comment: This is the way the Cesium api was written to work. It is very performant.

Answer (score 0):

Set the billboard's alignedAxis to Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Z instead of the default screen up vector. Run following sample in SandCastle to demonstrate that it works:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-111.572177, 40.582083);

var cesiumTerrainProviderMeshes = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider(
{ url : '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world' } 
);
 //viewer.terrainProvider = cesiumTerrainProviderMeshes;
 //viewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;

var ellipsoid = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid;
 var billboardCollection = viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.BillboardCollection(
{ scene : viewer.scene } 
));

billboardCollection.add(
{ position : position, image : '../images/facility.gif', //heightReference : Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND, rotation: Cesium.Math.PI/4, alignedAxis : Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Z } 
);
```